# Adding nested object to object with Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to add a nested item in Mongoose, but I can't seem to get it to work. I am trying to add the "messages" object to the existing "subitem" object

My JSON in MongoDB

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c33438d3d1e1323111fce6e"),
    "title" : "Nieuws",
    "__v" : 0,
    "subitem" : [ 
        {
            "title" : "Nieuwsberichten",
            "messages" : [ 
                {
                    "title" : "bericht1"
                }, 
                {
                    "title" : "bericht2"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "title" : "Nieuwsarchief"
        }, 
        {
            "title" : "Nieuwsbrief"
        }
    ]
}
```

In Express:

```
postController.postArticles = function(req, res,item) {
  var id = req.body.id;
  var saveData = {
    title: req.body.title,
    text: req.body.text
  };
  item.update({_id: id}, {$push:{'subitem.messages': saveData}},(err, result) => {
  });
};
```

And Mongoose Model:

```
var menuItems = new mongoose.Schema({
  title : String,
  subitem : {
    title: String,
    messages : {
      title: String,
      text: String
    }
  }
}, {collection: 'menu_items'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Schema does not match your JSON object.
In your Schema messages is an object, while in the JSON it is an array of objects.

Try the following Schema:

```
var menuItems = new mongoose.Schema({
  title : String,
  subitem : {
    title: String,
    messages : [{
      title: String,
      text: String
    }]
  }
}, {collection: 'menu_items'});
```